# GUROBI only uses single core to setup problem with cvxpy (python)

Tags: optimization, gurobi, cvxpy

I have a large MILP that I build with cvxpy and want to solve with GUROBI. When I give use the solve() function of cvxpy it take a really really really long time to setup and does not start solving for hours. Whilest doing that only 1 core of my cluster is being used. It is used for 100%. I would like to use multiple cores to build the model so that the process of building the model does not take so long. Running grbprobe also shows that gurobi knows about the other cores and for solving the problem it uses multiple cores.

I have tried to run with different flags i.e. turning presolve off and on or giving the number of Threads to be used (this seemed like i didn't even for the solving.

I also have reduce the number of constraints in the problem and it start solving much faster which means that this is definitively not a problem of the model itself.

The problem in it's normal state should have 2200 constraints i reduce it to 150 and it took a couple of seconds until it started to search for a solution.

The problem is that I don't see anything since it takes so long to get the ""set username parameters"" flag and I don't get any information on what the computer does in the mean time.

Is there a way to tell GUROBI or CVXPY that it can take more cpus for the build-up?
Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Find out where the time is lost. I guess it's cvxpy's DCP framework and last time i used it, the log (maybe *verbose* flag is needed) printed out the time used for cvxpy's operations. Gurobi itself will happily use whatever helps (see Erwins answer; root-solve will probably use *some* parallel processing too, at least concurrently solving the root with different algs), cvxpy won't because it can't (afaik). It's not easy to improve on this and we don't see your model, but in general, the code should exploit as much sparse algebra as possible, e.g. Yes: large matrix-mult; No: fine-grained loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry. The first part of the solve (cvxpy model generation, setup, presolving, scaling, solving the root, preprocessing) is almost completely serial. The parallel part is when it really starts working on the branch-and-bound tree. For many problems, the parallel part is by far the most expensive, but not for all.

This is not only the case for Gurobi. Other high-end solvers have the same behavior.

There are options to do less presolving and preprocessing. That may get you earlier in the B&B. However, usually, it is better not to touch these options.

Running things with `verbose=True` may give you more information. If you have more detailed questions, you may want to share the log.

Comment: When I put verbose in I can see that the bottleneck is the QpMatrixStuffing. Is there some way to increase the speed of this or some different library that I can use? Maybe also using gurobipy or something similar?

Comment: @1Pre You are paying the price for cvxpy doing it's canonicalization then. As mentioned in my comment, there is nothing you can do except for being as sparse-algebra friendly as possible within your modelling. The bigger step would be skipping cvxpy alltogehter and directly model it with gurobipy or other tools. This can be easy on some models (if you can wrap your model into the standard-form in your head, it's easy), less easy on others (when you exploit cvxpys tooling for some more complex stuff like transforming norms and such).